# SQL Server : use bigint variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Very simply, I am calling a procedure to get the primary key from one table, then storing the key in a variable so that I can then use it to insert into another table that needs a foreign key. The variable is what I expect it to be, however when I use it it returns nothing.

After trying looking at it, it appears to be that its an issue with the `WHERE` clause and using the variable

```
DECLARE @ClientId bigint;

SELECT * 
FROM Testing.dbo.Client 
WHERE ClientID = @ClientId
```

`@ClientId` value is 2

There is a value of 2 for a as a client ID in the table

When I run this I get the result I expect

```
select * 
from Testing.dbo.Client 
where ClientID = 2
```

This is where it gets set

```
DECLARE @ClientId int;
EXECUTE @ClientId = Testing.dbo.GetClientID @ClientName;
```

Where GetClientID is the following

```
USE Testing
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetClientId
    @ClientName nvarchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT ClientID FROM Testing.dbo.Client WHERE ClientName = @ClientName
GO
```

Worked out a bit more now, so the ClientId is not getting set after call to the proc

Comment: where/how do you set the value of @ClientId? Because in your snippet, you're only declaring it, not assigning a value.

Comment: While you can initialize in the `declare` as in the answer below, you would generally use `set` as in `set @ClientId = 2;`. In fact old versions of SQL Server don't let you do the inline initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out using OUTPUT variables which i had not come across before

```
USE Testing
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE AddReading
@ClientName NVARCHAR(50),
@MonitorName NVARCHAR(50),
@DateTime DATETIME,
@Temperature DECIMAL(12, 10),
@Humidity DECIMAL (12, 10),
@Staleness DECIMAL (12, 10)
AS 
DECLARE @ClientId int;
EXEC Testing.dbo.GetClientId @ClientName, @ClientId OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO Testing.dbo.Reading 
(ClientID, MonitorName, DateTime, Temperature, Humidity, Staleness)
VALUES (@ClientId, @MonitorName, @DateTime, @Temperature, @Humidity, @Staleness);
GO
```

Where proc GetClientId was

```
USE Testing
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetClientId
@ClientName nvarchar(50),
@ClientId bigint OUTPUT
AS 
Select @ClientId = ClientID FROM Testing.dbo.Client WHERE ClientName = @ClientName
GO
```

Please let me know if you believe this to be the best way of doing this, or if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: A scalar valued user defined function will probably be easier to use. In my experience neither the stored procedure (too hard to use) nor a function (encourages slow by slow, row by row, processing) are useful. The abstractions tend to be leaky, and querying the table or view directly pretty easy.

Comment: Without knowing the bigger picture, IMHO a better way would not be putting this trivial operation into a seperate stored procedure. Just put the code directly into the `AddReading` stored procedure. Unless the logic is complex and is reused by other things because it is complex.

Comment: I know this is old but if your `USE Testing` why would you `EXEC Testing.dbo.blahblah` and `INSERT INTO Testing.dbo.blahblah`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initalize variable otherwise it contains `NULL`;

```
DECLARE @ClientId bigint = 2; 
select * from Testing.dbo.Client where ClientID = @ClientId;
```

If you have it in argument list don't create variable with this name:

```
CREATE PROC stored_procedure
    @ClientID BIGING
AS
BEGIN
   select * from Testing.dbo.Client where ClientID = @ClientId;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If are you trying to set a variable with a store procedure this is the right way:

```
DECLARE @ClientId Table(ClientId int);

Insert Into @ClientId(ClientId)
Exec Testing.dbo.GetClientID @ClientName;

select * 
from Testing.dbo.Client 
where ClientID = (Select ClientId From @ClientId);
```

If your store procedure throws many rows change the `=` for `In` like this:

```
select * 
from Testing.dbo.Client 
where ClientID in (Select ClientId From @ClientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use like this:

```
DECLARE @ClientId int;
EXECUTE @ClientId = Testing.dbo.GetClientID @ClientName;
```

you can use RETURN @ClientID in the procedure

```
CREATE PROC proc_GetClientID
    @ClientNeme VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ClientID BIGINT
    SELECT @ClientID=1000
    RETURN @ClientID
END


DECLARE @ClientID INT
EXEC @ClientID =dbo.proc_GetClientID 'test'
SELECT @ClientID
```